# fastboost doesn't see device on linux even with su and sudo

Tags: adb, fastboot, linux, bootloader

so i Had a trouble booting into `download mode` on my Samsung Galaxy J4 to boot twrprecovery.img and not flashing it after enabling "developers options" and "USB debugging" and "Unlock OEM" now bootloader is already unlocked under "Unlock OEM" I tried `adb devices` it saw my phone I did `adb reboot bootloader` it did not boot into bootloader so after a little research I found I had to use `adb reboot download` I could enter download mode but when doing `fastboot devices` with normal, sudo and su privileges it simply doesn't see it while in OS mode nor in the download mode. I tried booting into bootloader via recovery mode using poweroff+Vol up+Homescreen and then navigating to reboot to bootloader it simply reboots to the OS.
so why adb sees devices but not fastboot?

```
anonsam-X550CC ~ # uname -r
4.4.0-127-generic
anonsam-X550CC ~ # cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.3"
VERSION_ID="18.3"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sylvia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

Phone Model : SM-J400F/DS
Baseband version : J400FXXU2ARI2
Build number : R16NW.J400FXXU2ARK2
Android version : 8.0.0
Android security patch level : November 1, 2018
```

Comment: Samsung devices do not have "fastboot" but use a proprietary system. You must use Odin/Heimdall to communicate with the device. You cannot communicate with a Samsung device with fastboot.

Comment: I'm not trying to flash i'm just trying to boot twrprecovery.img, I think odin/Jodin/Heimedall only flashes a rom

Comment: Still, Samsung devices do not support fastboot in any way, you can't just "boot" TWRP on them, you must flash it.